# C3 charts not rendering from jQuery data

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, c3.js

So I'm just getting into some simple UI stuff, and I'm stuggling with Javascript. I managed to get a couple of for-loops to create tags and render some charts, works great.

But I then used jquery to fetch a block of JSON data from a Spring Boot REST service.

```
    $.getJSON('api/randomData?chartCount=' + chartsToMake).done( function(data) {

    // Extract list of servers from the data...
    var hostList = []
    $.map(data, function(row) { hostList.push(row.host); });

    // Make it a unique list
    var uniqueHostList = hostList.unique();

    // Iterate over the unique list of servers
    uniqueHostList.forEach( function(host) {
        var tag = "chart" + host.replace(/\./g, "");
        var hostdata = data.filter( (v,i,a) => v.host === host)

        console.log("Processing Server:" + host + " with " + hostdata.length + " rows");

        // Create DOM element to bind the chart to
        document.getElementById("chartBlocks").innerHTML += "<div id=\"" + tag.replaceAll('#','') + "\"></div>";

        // Create the Chart here
        var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: "#" + tag,
            data: {
                json: hostdata,
                keys: { value: ['lowerband'] }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This gets an array of JSON strings back, each object contains one metric for a server, all the HTML tags are inserted, but only the last chart draws up.

I added lots of console.out() stuff to try and debug this, it has the data and everything seems to be working, and the last chart looks fine, but the other 3 above it dont populate.

I've been pulling my hair out trying to work out why, please help!
PS. I created a github project here which is a simple maven/spring boot application.
https://github.com/tfindlay-au/c3demo

There is a working page called "**working.html**" and "**index.html**" which doesnt work.

FWIW - it feels like a variable scope thing or maybe a timing thing if I'm trying to generate the chart before the data is avilable or something. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"only the last chart draws up."

```
document.getElementById("chartBlocks").innerHTML += "<div id=\"" + tag.replaceAll('#','') + "\"></div>";
```

Because that line (at first I thought it completely replaced the content but then I saw the += ) has bad side-effects for the existing content of chartblocks. Specifically it wipes out the event functionality (edit: and data) which setting up a c3.chart has attached to elements in that chart. When you then set innerHTML in chartblocks again, all that stuff is replaced by the innerHTML string, which is just a literal copy of the structure of the dom elements - wiping out any previously attached event handlers or data properties.

You instead need to append an extra div to chartblocks, which leaves the existing sibling charts in peace, and since c3 uses the d3 library you can do it like this:

```
d3.select("#chartBlocks").append("div").attr("id", tag.replace('#',''));
```

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem. I thought the += would append the content, and indeed it does seem to do that, but I wasnt aware of the side effect.

I will look into this more, I would like to understand how to track/debug this sort of thing in case it ever comes up again. Not that I'm going to become a UI person any time soon.

Thanks again for the explanation and the solution.

Comment: I should also say as well as the event functionality it removes the __data__ property that c3 (via d3) adds to the dom elements too, which is why the previously added charts, if they do appear, are empty. That's probably the most important of the two, but either will still cripple your chart (managing to preserve the data but losing the events means a visible but uninteractive chart)